# JQuery slideshow with Background-image and clickable position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this slideshow that I made with JQuery and the default transition each 4 seconds works well. However, when it comes to clicks on the dot navigation, the

1) The background-image associated with the curIndex dosen't show up
2) The .active class stays to the previous curIndex position until it is removed by the slideShow() function.
3) The function of de Setimeout Method seems to accelerate for some reason even if it is resetted by the clearTimeout variable.

I wish to have a clear understanding of JQuery methods so if you could clarify the reason why the dots navigation dosen't work it would be really appreciated.
The codepen is here: https://codepen.io/JeffyG/pen/QQeqvW

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slideshow - JFG Jquery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <section class="banner">
    <div class="wp-banner-navigation">
        <div class="wp-inner-banner-navigation">
            <ul>
                <li id="slide0" class="active"></li>
                <li id="slide1" class="inactive"></li>
                <li id="slide2" class="inactive"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slideshow"></div>
    </section>
</body>
<script src="slideshow.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

#slideshow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 400px;
    background: url('http://www.idatastart.com/static/images/home/xbanner2.jpg.pagespeed.ic.J9HEJAoOt0.webp') 50% middle center no-repeat;

    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% middle center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-width: 1080px;
}

#slideshow {
    opacity:1;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

#slideshow.fadeOut {
    opacity:0;
}

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
     background-color: #000;
}

.wp-banner-navigation {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 350px 45% 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.wp-inner-banner-navigation {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;    
    background-color: rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.5);
    border: 3px solid rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
    border-bottom: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px 100px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px 100px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 100px 100px 0px 0px;
    width: 182px;
    height: 50px;
}

.wp-banner-navigation ul {
    margin: 20px -10px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
.wp-banner-navigation li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;  
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.wp-banner-navigation li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.inactive {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.active {
    border: none !important;
    background: #0696d7 !important;
    background-color: #0696d7 !important;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var slideshowElement = $('#slideshow');
var imgArray = ['xbanner3.jpg.pagespeed.ic.cNoxcokJ-x.webp', 'xbanner2.jpg.pagespeed.ic.J9HEJAoOt0.webp', 'xbanner1.jpg.pagespeed.ic.HEfjRv7qD-.webp'];     
var navigationElement;
var breakTimeout;    
var dotArray = ['slide0', 'slide1', 'slide2'];

var curIndex = 0;
var imgDuration = 4000;

navigationElement = $('#slide0');

slideshowElement.css('background-image', 'url(http://www.idatastart.com/static/images/home/' + imgArray[curIndex] + ')'); 

var cachedImages = []; 

    for (var x = 0; x < imgArray.length; x++){ 
    cachedImages[x] = new Image(); 
    cachedImages[x].src = 'images/' + imgArray[x];
}    

$('.wp-inner-banner-navigation ul li').bind('click', function(){

    clearTimeout(breakTimeout);

    var index = $(this).index();

    curIndex = index;

    slideShow(curIndex);

    $("li[id^='slide']").removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");

    $("#slide" + index).addClass("active");

    $("#slide" + index).removeClass("inactive");

});

function slideShow() {

   slideshowElement.addClass('fadeOut');

    breakTimeout = setTimeout(function() {

            slideshowElement.css('background-image','url(http://www.idatastart.com/static/images/home/' + imgArray[curIndex]+ ')'); 
            slideshowElement.removeClass();
            navigationElement.addClass('inactive')
            navigationElement.removeClass('active');
            navigationElement = $("#" + dotArray[curIndex]);
            navigationElement.addClass('active');
            navigationElement.removeClass('inactive');
        },1000);

        curIndex++;

        if (curIndex == imgArray.length) { curIndex = 0; }
        setTimeout(slideShow, imgDuration);
}

slideShow();

});
```

Comment: I would suggest to use [owl carousel JS plugin](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html) which has many options to customise the slider.